# CKEDITOR Single Sided document view

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

I've been working on implementing ck editor in a current web app however one question that i haven't been able to find a definitive answer about is if the editor can be changed to show a single sided document view (so the user can see where pages would break). We had this functionality in previous wysiwyg editors (Edit-on-Ng) but i am curious to know if it is available for CK.

Sorry if this is not an appropriate question.

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the "[Basic CKEditor Concepts](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_basics-section-what-ckeditor-is-not)" article before you try to use CKEditor for things it was not designed for.

In particular:

> CKEditor is not **desktop publishing software** (it is not Word!) and is not a recommended tool to use when creating paged content with fixed layout and styling that is intended for printing.

There is a [Page Break](http://ckeditor.com/addon/pagebreak) plugin available that lets you partly imitate this functionality. When the plugin is enabled, the user will be able to insert a page break in a particular place and this should work for printing. However, the other part of the functionality that you described ("the user can see where pages would break") is not available. This is because you are working on HTML text whose flow depends on too many factors, like OS, browser, your screen resolution or window size so the editor will not know how this content fits a physical page.